# Compact Riemann surfaces as algebraic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying to grasp proofs of the fact that compact Riemann surfaces are algebraic curves. It seems as though no textbook fully treats this, and I wanted to ask about what was going on.  On one hand, I know that one can use Riemann-Roch to furnish meromorphic functions and then an embedding into projective space, whence it is possible to use something like Chow's Theorem to show that the image is algebraic. I would like to ask about a different approach:

I also know that once one shows that nonconstant meromorphic functions exist on any compact Riemann surface (e.g. using Riemann-Roch), it is possible to realize such a meromorphic function as providing a branched cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$; how exactly is this done, and how does this prove algebraicity?

Among others, Hartshorne and Miranda mention that showing existence of nonconstant meromorphic functions is a task in hard analysis: is that in order to prove Riemann-Roch, or is it independent?

Thank you - I would appreciate clarification on this equivalence of categories, and the direction of the implications in question/where certain tools get used.

Comment: It seems you are reading wrong books on Riemann surfaces.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan What are the right books then?

Comment: @Cornman For instance, Narasimhan's "Compact Riemann Surfaces" or "An Introduction to Riemann Surfaces" by Napier and Ramachandran. Both develop the "hard analysis" for working with Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the references. I'm familiar with Narasimhan's book, and he also employs Chow's theorem to ultimately show algebraicity, whereas I'm interested in the other approach which I mentioned. It seems like Napier and Ramachandran does not mention algebraic curves.

Comment: Narasimhan's book contains enough material to prove that a Riemann surface is algebraic, see my answer [here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409975/proving-algebraicity-of-compact-riemann-surfaces-without-chows-theorem/410040#410040).